# Can one ask for TeX related software recommendations here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

There is a dedicated site for software recommendations here on Stack Exchange but I'm not sure people there may know much about something like CDLatex.

I'm looking for a Latex IDE for Linux which has shortcuts like those of CDLatex, e.g. you press `z and you get \zeta. CDLatex is the main reason I use Emacs (in addition to its uncluttered interface). However recently I've had problems with either bugs or "misconfigurations".

Comment: What sort of recommendations? We have a [big question on IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides), for example.

Comment: As @Joseph suggests, we need to know more: Please, what would your question be, more precisely?

Comment: I added more detail.

Comment: I have the same doubt, to talking about imagemagik , software that recommend me in a post a months ago http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows